# How to get namedRanges by name in GAS project for Google Doc Add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am developing an Add-on for Google Docs using Google App Scripts. I wan to add and get namedRanges in document. I am setting namedRange to document as following

```
var rangeBuilder = doc.newRange();
rangeBuilder.addElement(textObj, urlObj.startOffset, urlObj.endOffset);
doc.addNamedRange(RangeManager.name, rangeBuilder.build());
```

I am retrieving all the namedRanges in the follwing way but it is returning an array with epmty object

```
var namedRange = doc.getNamedRanges(RangeManager.name); // gives [{}]
```

Can anyone please help me tell me what i am doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to retrieve the name of the range, you need to use the method `getName()`. As the designation `getNamedRanges()` suggests, the method will give you ALL NamedRanges with the same name, so you need to loop through them with `forEach`. In summary:

```
  var namedRange = doc.getNamedRanges("name_of_your_namerange").forEach(function(rangeEntry){
    (Logger.log("name: "+rangeEntry.getName()))})
```

Comment: in my example "RangeManager.name" contains the name of Range, but it returns empty array although i added ranges with the same name.

Comment: even if it contains the name, you still need to use the method getName() and you need to do it inside the loop.